# How to rewrite to Task<T> for performance gain?

Tags: c#, performance

I have the following code:

```
    static BlockingCollection<SimpleObject> sendQueue = new BlockingCollection<SimpleObject>();

    static public void Insert(string key, T value)
    {
        SimpleObject simpleObject = new SimpleObject {Key = key, Value = value};
        sendQueue.Add(simpleObject);
        var data = sendQueue.Take(); //this blocks if there are no items in the queue.

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            //Do ASYNC stuff with data here - threadsafe
        });
    }
```

How can I write this to use Task of T and still make sure it's threadsafe and fast? Or is there a better/faster way?

Comment: What about your current implementation makes it thread safe?

Comment: @mch_dk is this the real code, so you insert and then immediately take an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need 2 threads/tasks. 1 Producer and 1 Consumer.

```
//Producer
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
        {
            sendQueue.Add(new SimpleObject() { Key = "", Value = "" });
        }
        sendQueue.CompleteAdding();
    });

//Consumer
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach(var so in sendQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-write this using the TPL would be relatively straightfoward

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // do async stuff
});
```

However, this doesn't making anything thread-safe this just makes sure the work is run on a separate thread. Also, whether it's going to be faster is debatable, you would need to benchmark it.